# Fail during start Tomcat v9.0 CDI annotations

Tags: java, serialization, session-scope

When I was trying to start my server, this problem appeared. I've checked the project and the problem seems to be the CDI annotation "@ViewScope", at the moment I change it to another annotation everything starts working properly. I do not realize why this annotation is causing problems! Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Escola]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Escola]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnserializableDependencyException: WELD-001413: The bean Managed Bean [class web.AlumneBean] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any] declares a passivating scope but has a non-passivation-capable dependency Managed Bean [class model.Alumne] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointPassivationCapable(Validator.java:442)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:380)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:277)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:130)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:151)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:494)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

nov 12, 2018 9:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:960)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Escola]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Escola]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnserializableDependencyException: WELD-001413: The bean Managed Bean [class web.AlumneBean] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any] declares a passivating scope but has a non-passivation-capable dependency Managed Bean [class model.Alumne] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointPassivationCapable(Validator.java:442)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:380)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:277)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:130)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:151)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:494)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

nov 12, 2018 9:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:960)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:960)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Escola]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Escola]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnserializableDependencyException: WELD-001413: The bean Managed Bean [class web.AlumneBean] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any] declares a passivating scope but has a non-passivation-capable dependency Managed Bean [class model.Alumne] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointPassivationCapable(Validator.java:442)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:380)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:277)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:130)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:151)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:494)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

nov 12, 2018 9:15:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMACIÓN: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
nov 12, 2018 9:15:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMACIÓN: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
nov 12, 2018 9:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Parando servicio [Catalina]
nov 12, 2018 9:15:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMACIÓN: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
nov 12, 2018 9:15:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMACIÓN: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
nov 12, 2018 9:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
ADVERTENCIA: The web application [Escola] appears to have started a thread named [weld-worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
nov 12, 2018 9:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
ADVERTENCIA: The web application [Escola] appears to have started a thread named [weld-worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
nov 12, 2018 9:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
ADVERTENCIA: The web application [Escola] appears to have started a thread named [weld-preloader-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)

     java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

AlumneBean:

```
package web;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import model.Alumne;
import model.EscolaDAO;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class AlumneBean implements Serializable
{



    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7672809628464912860L;

    private String codigo;

    @Inject
    private Alumne alumne;

    @Inject
    private EscolaDAO escolaDAO;


    public String getCodigo()
    {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo)
    {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        alumne = escolaDAO.getAlumne(codigo);
    }

    public Alumne getAlumne()
    {
        return alumne;
    }

    public String guardar()
    {
        return "alumnes?faces-redirect=true";
    }


}
```

Alumne:

```
package model;

import java.util.*;

public class Alumne extends DadesBasiques
{

    private Set<Assignatura> assignaturesMatriculades = new HashSet<>();
    private Curs Curs;


    public Set<Assignatura> getAssignaturesMatriculades()
    {
        return assignaturesMatriculades;
    }

    public void setAssignaturesMatriculades(Set<Assignatura> assignaturesMatriculades)
    {
        this.assignaturesMatriculades = assignaturesMatriculades;
    }

    public Curs getCurs()
    {
        return Curs;
    }

    public void setCurs(Curs curs)
    {
        Curs = curs;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like either `AlumneBean` is not serializable, or a property contained in that class is not serializable.

Comment: Show class `AlumneBean`

Comment: @user7294900 done!

Comment: Great, show also class `Alumne` that was injected

Comment: @user7294900 done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272489/unserializabledependencyexception-weld-001413-the-bean-declares-a-passivating) you are injecting a non serialized `Alumne` in  serialized Bean `AlumneBean`, you can declare it as `transient` to prevent such error

```
@Inject
transient private Alumne alumne;
```

> In CDI, there are some scopes (most often SessionScope) which require beans to be Serializable - mostly because they are somehow connected to HTTP Session, which can contain more objects that fit into memory and from time to time the server may need to swap them to disk.
>
> It seems you got this because InfoPageController implements Serializable. But this is not enough according to Java serialization principles. You need to ensure that all member fields of your Serializable class are one of: - primitive type (int, boolean) - an object that is serializable (all serialization rules apply recursively) - the field is marked with keyword transient (which is placed at the same level as e.g. private keyword)